# Relationship between code optimization and data compression

Tags: optimization, compilation, compiler-construction, compression, list-comprehension

I searched on the Internet about this question and Found that some researchers used data compression algorithms for compiler optimization like Huffman coding.

My question is more general :

Can we consider code optimization as lossy type of compression?

Comment: You can't consider it as a lossy kind of anything, because it isn't lossy, and Huffman coding is not a compiler optimization technique. Your question doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: I am voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: http://aggregate.org/TechPub/lcpc2002.pdf

Comment: No. The kind of optimization you refer to is very specific. Most optimizations (e.g. Loop unrolling) tend to make the code larger.

Answer (score 0):

At a concrete level, it's apples and oranges. But at an abstract level it's an interesting question.

Data compression deals with redundancy, which is the difference between data and information.
It seeks to reduce needless redundancy by revising the coding of the information.
Often this coding works by taking a common substring and making a code that refers to it, rather that repeating the substring.

Compiler optimization (for speed) seeks to reduce needless cycles.
One way is if the result of some computation is needed twice or more,
make sure it is saved in some address or register (memoizing) so it can be re-used with fewer cycles.

Another form of encoding numbers is so-called "unary notation" where there is only one digit, and numbers are represented by repeating it. For example, the numbers "three" and "four" are "111" and "1111", which takes N digits.
This code is optimized by switching to binary, as in "011" and "100", which takes log(N) digits (base 2, of course).

A programming analogy to this is the difference between linear and binary search.
Linear search takes O(N) comparisons.
Each comparison can yield either a lot of information or very little - on average much less than a bit.
Binary search takes O(log(N)) comparisons, with each comparison yielding one bit.

With some thinking, it should be possible to find other parallels.

Comment: My question is that both of them aim at removing redundancies while preserving the semantics of the code/data at the same time.